# How to display music in a category when a category is clicked (without a page refresh) in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a website for a music database.

I would like to display categories like classical and hip hop first; when the user clicks on a category, I would like to display all the tracks names in that category (I would like to do this without a page refresh). I would also need to support pagination of this list displaying 10 items in one page (and I need to display buttons for display, edit, delete alongside each track in this list)

How can I accomplish this? Does bootstrap provide components that support this kind of implementation?

(If I could do this with a page refresh, I have done this before and I would know how to do it. But I am not sure how to do this without a page refresh)

Comment: And I also need to be able to do a full text search on this list. (Is it possible to do a full text search implementation without doing a page refresh?)

Comment: If you want to do it without a page refresh, then you will have to make use of AJAX (possibly via a front end framework like React, ELM). Bootstrap won't help you - that is just for styling. In short either you'll need to write some javascript/jquery or you'll need to consider using a front end framework. I would suggest you implement what you want with a "refresh" and once you have that working, to consider the alternatives i've just mentioned.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon - Thanks much for your reply! Is it possible to implement this as some kind of a tree view in bootstrap - so I first display 2 collapsed trees - 1) category and 2) rating. When the user clicks on either of the two, then I just expand the tree to show the list of all tracks corresponding to that facet. Would that not be possible in bootstrap?

Comment: bootstrap can supply the functionality to collapse and expand tress. But where will the data of all that cone from? It must come either from instance variables from a controller action when the page is loaded OR you must use AJAX / javascript / front-end-framework (all amount to the same thing btw) to query another controller/action to fetch the data you want WITHOUT a "refresh" happening.

Comment: can't the tree load all the data the first time the page is loaded? So the tree will load all the data the first time the page is loaded, but it will still be collapsed and just won't display the data; when the user clicks on the tree or the facet name, the tree would expand and display all the contents (the contents were all loaded when the page was accesses the very first time so there would be no need for a page refresh this time). That sounds like a reasonable requirement; but I have not worked on trees in bootstrap before.

Comment: It tried googling and found some interesting tree components that bootstrap provides; but all the tree contents seem to display one single string and I am not sure if it is possible to have a multi-column display inside the tree contents (let alone adding buttons in the last column of the contents for performing CRUD operations)

Comment: I was wondering if we could do this using data tables. First only the name of the table should be displayed and when the user clicks on the name, the table should be displayed in full (this should not cause a page refresh as well I hope). Does that sound reasonable to you? I have posted this as another question as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058109/is-it-possible-to-make-a-datable-collapsible

Comment: You are missing the point. You are focusing on display the data while ignoring providing data to view.

Comment: @Biju just like Catmal says: use bootstrap to display the data. use rails to provide that data. you can "load all the data the first time the page is loaded" but be careful because if you load too much data, then your app is liable to performance issues later on - this is not a problem now - you can optimize for this later. Just get it up and running like you suggest and progress forward from there.

Answer (score 0):

On views/categories/index.html.erb:

```
 <% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= link_to category_path(category), :remote => true do %>
   <%= category.name %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="category_<%= category.id %>">
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

Then create a partial views/categories/_show.html.erb (here you can insert a table or a structure with bootstrap row and columns):

```
<% @category.tracks.each do |track| %>
<%= track.name %>
... and you can add here delete and edit actions

<% end %>
```

Then create views/categories/show.js.erb:

```
$(".category_<%= @category.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("show")) %>");
```

Fyi what you are trying to do has nothing to do with bootstrap, unless you wanted for instance display tracks on a bootstrap modal.

Comment: would this cause a page refresh?

Comment: great! Thanks much @Catmal - I will try this.

Comment: The first code snippet in your answer - if I use that in application.html.erb, then where should I place _show.html.erb and show.js.erb please? I apologise for the basic questions but I am fairly new to Rails and MVC as such - so kindly bear with me!

Comment: I updated the answer. I named them categories and tracks but you should replace with actual names of your models. Same way I used name attribute but you should replace with actual attribute

Comment: Do not use the first code on application.html.erb, as you probably don't have @categories available there..

Comment: Thanks much @Catmal - I will try this. Also, would you be able to help me with implementing an appropriate 5-star based rating system for the tracks please? I have posted a question for this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033680/control-to-give-star-ratings-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: if instead of Category as a model, if I would just like to use Music as the model (Music contains category as one of its fields), how should I change this code that you showed? Pls help!

Comment: You are going out of topic now. you should stick to question title, for which my answer should work. if it works please accept it..

Comment: I already have `@categories` in `MusicController`. So I used this in `movies/index.html.erb` - `<% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <tr><td><%= link_to category, '/music/_show_category', :category => category, :remote => true%></td></tr>
    <% end %>` and I am using a `/music/_show_category.html.erb` which contains the code to list all the tracks in the category (which I am getting inside the partial by `params[:category]` [hoping this should give me the category which was selected by the user])

Comment: may I just ask if you could explain how the JavaScript works with your erb code? I am missing the connection. Sorry to ask simple questions again!

Comment: You create .js.erb instead of html.erb. You render a partial (_show in the example) inside a div instead of a full html page. adding remote: true to a link will render js instead of html. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a poor man's bootstrap example I  whipped up: when you click on the `Track Category` example, the table should expand. (You must have bootstrap v4 set up for this to work) and you must have a `track_table` partial as well - you can use the same partial for the two different tables that you want:

```
  <div class="track-group">
    <div class="track track-default">
      <div class="track-heading">
        <h4 class="track-title">
          <p data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1"> Track Category (Click to Expand)</p>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="track-collapse collapse">
        <div class="track-body">
          <%= render 'track-table' %>
        </div>
        <div class="track-footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's how it looks with an existing app on my computer:

[image: Sample of Expanding the section]